# Flutter pixel overflow issue

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have designed a login page using `Form` in flutter but when I am selecting text in the `FormInputField` it is showing overflow by 3 pixels as shown in the figure:
[image: flutter ui problem]
How can I solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug.

There is a Pull Request open with a temporary solution, it's just missing a bugfix and the appropriate tests: [PR](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/38561)

You can find the temporary solution in this [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/35826)